# UILabel not updating connected with IBOutlet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

I am trying to update the UILabel of IBOutlet, however for some reason the content is not getting updated. Initially, the content is getting loaded from the model, which performs jsonResponse in async. However, I have set a delegate once the content is there to update the layout for which I am calling setNeedsDisplay.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks.

The code below:

```
@interface pd ()

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *pD;
@property (nonatomic, retain) pd_model *pdModel;

@end

@implementation pd

@synthesize pD = _pD, pdModel;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil :(NSDictionary*)pD {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.productDetails = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:pD];
        self.pdModel = [[ProductDetails_Model alloc] init:pD];
        self.pdModel.delegate = self;
        NSLog(@"%@",[self.pD description]);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    productRecCarousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, scrollView.contentSize.height, 320.0f, 100.0)];
    productRecCarousel.delegate = self;

    [scrollView addSubview:productRecCarousel];

    [self addProductDescription];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.pdModel responseCode]);
    [soldBy setText:[self.pdModel responseCode]];
    //[soldBy setText:@"1"];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark CarouselDelegate methods
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel {

    return 1;
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel {

    return 1;
}

- (UIView*)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    return [[UIView alloc] init];
}

- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel {
    //usually this should be slightly wider than the item views
    return 150;
}

- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel transformForItemView:(UIView *)view withOffset:(CGFloat)offset {
    //implement 'flip3D' style carousel

    //set opacity based on distance from camera
    view.alpha = 1.0 - fminf(fmaxf(offset, 0.0), 1.0);

    //do 3d transform
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = _carousel.perspective;
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, M_PI / 8.0, 0, 1.0, 0);
    return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0, 0.0, offset * _carousel.itemWidth);
}

- (void)addProductDescription {

    NSLog(@"%f",addProductDetails.frame.size.height);
    addProductDetails.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, productRecCarousel.frame.size.height, addProductDetails.frame.size.width, addProductDetails.frame.size.height);
    [scrollView addSubview:addProductDetails];


}

- (void)updateTheLayout {

    //[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
   //This is where I get the delegate called once the model is being updated. I tried scrollView and self.view setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout but the IBoutlet never gets updated which is in "ViewDidLoad as assigned as" : [soldBy setText:[self.pdModel responseCode]];

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what you're doing...

Comment: @JShapiro, have added the code. Please comment if you see anything there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `[soldBy setText:[self.pdModel responseCode]];` in your callback, not in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 4):

so you just have to call `[soldBy setText:[self.pdModel responseCode]];` from `updateTheLayout` and not from `viewDidLoad` because it is not ready yet. And please make sure to update the UI elements from the main thread.

Comment: I could only answer one right, but you got the right answer too. Thanks @Ezeki

Comment: yeah, i was late for 1 minute =)